# Dropdown menu for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a way to do it, or a simple "You have to use JavaScript."

Is it possible to make a pure CSS dropdown menu for mobile devices, or do I have to use JavaScript?

I tried using the :focus pseudo, but I can't click the links, even though the menu opens (It closes before the link in clicked).
The :active pseudo doesn't even work half way.

So is there some trick to doing this, or do I need to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `:checked` pseudoclass works in [all major mobile browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

The way you can do this is the following:

```
<input class="dropdowninput" type="checkbox" id="dropdownbox1"/>
<div class="dropdownbox">
    <label for="dropdownbox1">Open dropdown</label>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>...</li><li>etc</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.dropdowninput, .dropdown {display:none;}
.dropdowninput:checked + .dropdownbox .dropdown {display:block;}
```

That way, your dropdown `ul` will only show up when the checkbox is checked. The disadvantage might be that when the dropdown is opened, it will only close if it's manually closed by the user.

You could also use `:hover` which is probably the effect you're looking for:

```
<div class="dropdown">
Open
    <ul>
        <li>asdf</li>
        <li>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

With CSS:

```
.dropdown ul {display:none;}
.dropdown:hover ul {display:block;}
```

[this](http://jsbin.com/ULaHaqe/1/) simple jsbin works for me on my Chrome on Android.

This works because the nested `ul` is still hovered on when clicking anything within the dropdown, while the "triggering" label element is not focused anymore when clicking something inside. Also, the `:active` probably doesn't work because of how mobile browsers work, but I wouldn't really know that to be honest.

Comment: :hover will work on a touch device now if you just touch something? The checkbox idea is genius, but I don't like the usability of having to manually close it.

Comment: @David My experience is that `:hover` generally works just fine in mobile browsers too. I don't really have a lot of experience with different `:hover` situations with mobile browsers, but I've just finished making [this MediaWiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Tabs) which uses almost exactly the same idea, and in testing that, `:hover` seemed to work perfectly in all Android browsers. I did run into a few small "rerender" issues with `:checked` for Android Browser and Dolphin, where styles are not recalculated as smoothly as you'd expect.

Comment: This wonderful solution is well explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked including a live example.